# Flashlight for night open water swimming

Tags: gear, swimming, flashlights

My swimming season ended for me when it's dark before I manage to get out of work, eat something and get to the beach.

I'd like to continue swimming, but I want to see where I swim and be seen.

What are the flashlight solutions for the open water swimming? I've checked in a local scuba dive shop, but scuba dive lights seem totally unfit for swimming - they need hands to operate, which is not a problem for scuba diver who doesn't use hands to propel, but I can't imagine crawling with them.

Comment: Googling ‘waterproof swimming light’ pulls up a bunch of reasonable looking options for open water swimming.

Comment: Just a waterproof headlamp? They are quite cheap nowadays.

Comment: @phipsgabler the problem with 'waterproof' is, that in best case it claims it won't stop working in rain, not that it can be used under water. And with cheap aliexpress crap even that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Well, the one I have is [IPX8-rated](https://eu.blackdiamondequipment.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-bdel/default/dw211de51b/instructions/S17/M11145_C_ReVolt_IS-WEB.pdf), which means it is tested to work under full immersion. Officially for 30 minutes only, but I would definitely go swimming with it. (For comparison: pool and bathtub lights are usually rated IP68.)

Comment: I think your desires are exclusive.  A light designed to allow people to see you would not be very good for you to use to see ahead.  I'd consider towing a strobe to be seen, and mounting a small, well-focused (spot) scuba lamp on a chest harness to illuminate what's ahead.

Comment: My preferences, but I would concentrate on being seen, rather than seeing.  The reason I say this is that I find a flashlight does a wonderful job at killing my night vision.  In many cases, and I would rate night swimming as one of those, your night vision, once habituated should be enough to allow you to move with confidence, given some moonlight or urban lighting.  On the other hand, I could see value in combining glow sticks with a swimming cap somehow to be more visible to boats.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica my consideration is, I'd would myself with some obstacle like rock or a pillar that I wouldn't see, but assuming I'd never swim in an area that I haven't explored by daylight, I guess I should be OK. 
Being seen is more crucial.

Answer (score 1):

Google "Adventure lights for swimming". These can be used for your purpose. They are used in channel swimming as well.